# how to match a entire block of text and insert lines after in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am attempting to match a entire block of text in a file and then i need to insert a new line after. The entire block needs to be matched as each of the lines repeat else where in the code

```
<DirectoryMatch ".*/wp-admin/" >
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Authenticate'
Require valid-user

order deny,allow
deny from all
```

and below the deny statement it would insert `allow ip from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Questions:  (1)  What have you already done?  (2)  What's the block that needs to be matched?  Is it exactly what you posted in your code block, in its entirety, letter-for letter?  Is it just the first 5 lines?

Comment: Try something with awk: Make an array with the lines that should match and a counter how many consecutive lines matched when processing the file. When all lines are matched, reset the counter and add the deny string.

Comment: Andrew, 1) posted here, read quite a bit not sure on how to sed after a block 2)That is the block that needs to be matched... 3)its all the lines

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, instead of hacking something together with sed or awk and praying that no one will ever put inconvenient whitespaces anywhere into my config file, I'd use Perl and the [Apache::Admin::Config](http://search.cpan.org/~markwhi/Apache-Admin-Config/lib/Apache/Admin/Config.pm) library from CPAN to properly parse and modify the config file.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Apache::Admin::Config;

# Parse config (first command line argument is the file name)
# The indent level is used for the output reformatting at the end, not to read
# the existing configuration.
my $conf = new Apache::Admin::Config($ARGV[0], -indent => 2)
    or die $Apache::Admin::Config::ERROR;

# Extract all DirectoryMatch sections
my @dirmatch = $conf->section("DirectoryMatch");

# Of those sections:
for my $dm (@dirmatch) {
    # Pick those (hopefully the one) that applies to ".*/wp-admin/"
    if($dm->value eq '".*/wp-admin/"') {
        # In that section, find all deny directives
        my @deny_directives = $dm->directive('deny');

        # If there are some:
        if(@deny_directives) {
            # insert allow directive after the last of them
            $dm->add_directive('allow' => 'from ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                               -after => $deny_directives[-1]);
        } else {
            # Otherwise just insert it at the end.
            $dm->add_directive('allow' => 'from ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
        }
    }
}

# When done, dump the changed config.
# If reformatting is not desired, use dump_raw instead of dump_reformat.
print $conf->dump_reformat;
```

Put this in a file, say `foo.pl`, and run `perl foo.pl foo.conf`, where `foo.conf` is your Apache config file.

Note that I made some assumptions about the semantics of your use case that may or may not fit 100% and may or may not require some tweaking to work perfectly for you. Either way, it should at least give you a starting point and a rough idea of how the library works (documentation is behind the link, too).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/deny from all/, "deny from all\nallow ip from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")}1' file 
<DirectoryMatch ".*/wp-admin/" >
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Authenticate'
Require valid-user

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow ip from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```